# phpMyAdmin - Can connect to DB but cant pull data

Tags: mysql, xampp

Here is my connect.php file

```
<?php
$connect_error = "Sorry, experiencing temporary connection problems";
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ($connect_error);
mysql_select_db("cl_db");
?>
```

If I change the localhost to something bogus, I get the error as expected. So it is actually connecting to the database. I am having trouble actually pulling any data though from a DB i created called cl_db.

Would there be any sort of settings in phpmyadmin that would allow me to connect to a database, however not allow me to interact with a table in the database?

my users.php

```
function user_exists($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;

}
```

I attached the following code to a sign in button to verify it can atleast get data from the DB.

```
if (user_exists("test1") === true) {
    echo 'exist';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

It prints false when I know for a fact that username exists in the database.

Comment: Can we see the syntax you are using to query (or `pull` as you are saying) from the database?

Comment: what is the error on the select call?

Comment: @Young Millie sure, let me update my post. just a minute

Comment: @johnelemans, no particular error. just cant find it

Comment: There is a particular error. call mysql_error() to get it and all will be revealed!

Comment: Im not getting any errors.